# How can I style Mapbox markers being pulled in directly from Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am new to Mapbox, so please bear with me.

I have uploaded my geoJson to my Mapbox map and am now editing it via javascript, creating the map by calling the following function.

```
$scope.initMap = function() {
   var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example.hk78fg64');
};
```

The map works fine, but I want to style the default markers. How can I style these markers being pulled in from Mapbox directly? All examples for styling them have the markers being created on the spot inside the geoJson function (view the expression below)

```
L.geoJson(geoJson, {
    pointToLayer: L.mapbox.marker.style,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [L.mapbox.map documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-mapbox-map/):

```
$scope.initMap = function() {
   var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example.hk78fg64', { featureLayer: {
       pointToLayer: L.mapbox.marker.style }
   });
};
```